# what does delay do in c?

Tags: c, delay, turbo-c++

when we put put delay, it will put a delay between doing the up line and down line or it will put a delay in doing all of the lines in our code?

```
int main()
{
  if ( kbhit() )
  {
   E = getCommand();
   doCommand(E);
   delay(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: create a simple time-delay. to execute next statement

Comment: `delay` is the same as `msleep`

Comment: @mvp msleep pauses where it's called?

Comment: yes, it does. `msleep` is not always available, can be simulated via `usleep(x*1000)`

Comment: tnx...  I learned a new thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard `delay` function, but many non-standard headers (like dos.h) and custom implementations are available in which it is used to suspend execution of a program for a particular time.

So, after executing `doCommand(E)`, your program will wait for 100 milliseconds, i.e. it will pause for that time period, before executing further.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function called `delay()` in C. But it will very probably just insert a pause at the place where the function is called, that's a very common design.

Since the shown code doesn't loop or anything, it will just pause, then exit.

Comment: well, I'm writing a code in turbo c++. I've seen this delay() in coding c++, but now coding I'm a bit confused.... thanks anyway( you helped in it's function). @unwind

Comment: @NoorNk: Just as a side note, avoid using functions like `kbhit()` from  which is also a non-standard function from `conio.h`. Use of standard functions is always recommended.

Comment: @payeli : like what? i do not know much about standard or non-standard  functions...

Comment: @NoorNk: avoid using functions like kbhit()